# Hibernate Many-To-Many mapping deletes child entity

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many

I'm trying to create many-to-many relation with hibernate, but it doesn't work as i expect.

Here is my entities.

LetterCreditAgreement:

```
@Canonical
@CompileStatic
@Entity
@Table(name = "FP_LETTER_OF_CREDIT_AGREEMENT")
class LetterCreditAgreement {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "DOC_ID")
    Long id

    ...

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "FP_DOCUMENT_CURRENCY_LINK",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "DOC_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CURRENCY_ID"))
    List<Currency> otherCurrency

    ...
}
```

Currency (which is a dictionary and represented as view in database):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "V_CURRENCY")
@Canonical
@CompileStatic
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
class Currency extends SuperEntity {
    @Column(name = "name")
    String name

    @Column(name = "short_name")
    String shortName

    @Column(name = "ident")
    String ident

    @Column(name = "code")
    String code

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "type_id")
    MeasureUnitType type
}
```

Linked entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FP_DOCUMENT_CURRENCY_LINK")
@Canonical
@CompileStatic
class DocumentCurrencyLink {

   @EmbeddedId
   DocumentCurrencyPK pk

   @Embeddable
   @Canonical
   @CompileStatic
   static class DocumentCurrencyPK implements Serializable {
       @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
       @JoinColumn(name = "doc_id")
       Document document

       @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
       @JoinColumn(name = "currency_id")
       Currency currency
   }
}
```

Code that saves or updates main entity:

```
LetterCreditAgreement detached = mapper.toEntity(form.data)
LetterCreditAgreement loc = repository.findOne(locId)

...

if (detached.otherCurrency != null) {
        entityUtil.mergeLists(loc.otherCurrency, detached.otherCurrency)
}

...

loc = repository.save(detached)
```

I'm expecting that hibernate deletes relationships from FP_DOCUMENT_CURRENCY_LINK table, but it also trying to remove Currency which are not in otherCurrency list anymore:

```
Hibernate: delete from table.fp_document_currency_link where doc_id=?
Hibernate: insert into table.fp_document_currency_link (doc_id, currency_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into table.fp_document_currency_link (doc_id, currency_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into table.fp_document_currency_link (doc_id, currency_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into table.fp_document_currency_link (doc_id, currency_id) values (?, ?)
```

This is ok, but next:

```
Hibernate: delete from table.v_currency where id=?
```

I don't want that to happen. Is this normal behavior i should expect from hibernate? I don't want currency being removed from database because it's a dictionary, i just want to remove relations when otherCurrency list changes. how can I achieve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define the Cascade Type of `List<Currency> otherCurrency` in the `LetterCreditAgreement` to {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}. This explicitly tells Hibernate to only Persist and Merge changes that are saved from this class. 
Further try to avoid using List, rather use Set.
There is also a good Blog-Article from Vlad Mihalcea: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/ that goes further into detail.

I can just recommend to read regularly his blog.

Comment: Еhanks for the reply, I tried to do it but it still tries to remove currency:

`Hibernate: delete from table.v_currency where id=?`

Comment: Hmmm. It would be helpful to see the code where you add Currencies to LCA and how you save/merge those. Anyways is there are reason why you don't have getters and setters for your variables?